# Sorting a stack with another temporary stack in c gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, stack

I have a program where i implement a stack with a linked list and sort it with another temporary stack.I think it's supposed to work but it outputs segmentation fault.

This part is the declaration of the stack functions

```
typedef struct Node{
    int val;
    struct Node*next;
}node;

void init(node *t){//initialize 
    t=NULL;
}

int isempty(node *n){//check if empty
    if(n==NULL){return 1;}
    return 0;
}

void push(node *t,int val){
    node *temp;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(temp==NULL){
        exit(0);
    }
    temp->val=val;
    temp->next=t;
    t=temp;
}

void pop(node *s){
    int t;
    node *temp;
    temp=s;
    t=temp->val;
    s=s->next;
    free(temp);  
}

int topSt(node *s){//returns top of the stack
    return s->val;
}
```

The function where the stack gets sorted

```
node *sortStack(node *input){//sorting the stack
    node *temp;
    int t;
    while(!isempty(input)){
        t=topSt(input);
        pop(input);
        
        while(!isempty(temp) && topSt(temp)>t){
            push(input,topSt(temp));
            pop(temp);
        }
        push(temp,t);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Display function to print the elements of the stack

```
void display(node *head){//display the stack's elements
    while(head != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", head->val);
        head=head->next;
    }
}
```

The main function

```
int main(){
    node *top;
    init(top);
    push(top,9);
    push(top,45);
    push(top,21);
    push(top,5);
    node *sorted=sortStack(top);
    display(sorted);
}
```

Comment: This function void init(node *t){//initialize 
    t=NULL;
} does not make a sense and has no effect. That is after these two lines node *top;
    init(top); the pointer top is not initialized. It is enough to write node *top = NULL;

Comment: Many problems. In is this in `pop`: `s=s->next;` The `s` variable is local to the function. Setting it does not change the caller's value. Result is freed memory remains in the caller's stack structures.

Comment: Also, in `sortStack`, the variable `node *temp;` is never initialized.